# python3 convert byte class to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, encode

I receive data from a socket in Python 3 with

```
data = ""
...
data = s.recv(1024)
```

When I want to `print(data)` and `print (type(data))`, it tells me:

```
b'contentofdata'
<class 'bytes'>
```

How can I convert `data` back to a string so it only shows `contentofdata` after `print(data)`? I tried a lot with `.decode` or `.encode`, but it does not seem to work in Python 3.

Comment: It's just `data.decode()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `str(data, 'utf-8')` to convert bytes to string.